# Как сделать раскрывающийся текст (как на фото)?

Tags: css

То есть, нужно что бы часть текста была полупрозрачна, но видна, а остальная часть открывалась, когда нажимаешь "читать полностью" и весь текст становился нормального цвета.
Спасибо всем кто поможет!)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужно, что бы что бы вначале текст показывался частично(+цвет текста был как бы с затуханием), а при начатии на "читать полностью", текст раскрывался полностью. Вот сайт оригинал ( внизу) https://wolf.ua/

Answer (score 2):

Сначала прописываешь элементам ~ `opacity: 0.3` (в которых находится часть текста которая должна быть полупрозрачной)

Далее при помощи метода `.addEventListener` сначала вешаешь событие `mouseenter`, при котором немного показываешь текст, а после событие `click` на элемент, в котором у тебя текст Читать полностью

Вот небольшой пример:

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.list');
const nextText = document.querySelector('.nextText');
list.addEventListener('mouseenter', ()=>{
    nextText.classList.add('opacity') ;
})
list.addEventListener('mouseleave', ()=>{
    nextText.classList.remove('opacity') ;
})
list.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    list.classList.add('hide');
    nextText.classList.add('show');
    nextText.classList.remove('opacity') ;
})
```

```css
.list{
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: blue;
  
}
.list:hover{
cursor:pointer;

}

.nextText{
opacity:0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
}

.show{
opacity: 1;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.opacity{
opacity:0.3;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.hide{
opacity:0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Типография Вольф .......</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum, et?</p>
<p class="list">Читать полностью</p>
<p class="nextText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, nam.</p>
```